# How to force linux to use one network connection over the other?

Tags: iphone, linux, networking, tethering

I have connected my iPhone which has hotspot enabled to my ubuntu machine through the USB.

Based on the type of network activity (say browsing vs ssh), I want to switch between network connections (usb-wired vs lan).

Is there a command that allow me switch on the fly?

Edit:
I'm looking for a simpler solution, just the one that replaces without me having to pull out the cable.

My Sessions are separate. It's literally -- hey I have to check my personal emails, but I don't want to do it my company server. So, I'm looking for a solution like this

Answer (score 3):

Usually when I end up in situations like this I use static routes to divide the traffic. **But** this sort of depends on that you know the sites you would connect to. But it could quite easily be made in to a script that could be executed when you need it, and the changes is non-volatile.

The trick here is to decide which interface that should be the default route and after that add static routes for the destinations that you would like to take the other path. I use the *ip* command for this its quite straight forward.

> ip route add 1.3.3.7/32 via 192.168.10.1
>
> ip route add 1.4.4.0/24 via 192.168.10.1

A more advanced and permanent solution would be to do this with *iptables*, this allows you to use more granular rules as well. Take a look at [this](http://blog.khax.net/2009/12/01/multi-gateway-balancing-with-iptables/) guide, I wont make what you asked for but it has the basics on how to use iptables for multi gateway balancing.

Comment: I like your approach(so have an upvote), but I'm really looking for a simple switch, sort of an incognito mode in the browser. 


i.e I'd don't mind a manual operation between every switching.

Lets say I have a script 'switchme'. I simply execute this command everytime I want to toggle

Comment: Well, just make a [launcher](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles) for your script and your're there. :)

Answer (score 1):

Userspace shouldn't be able to select the route it uses. If you just want to
use one route for SSH traffic, and one for HTTP traffic, do the following. Note
that the approach below is used because we are routing based on the layer 4
destination address. Were it just IP based, you could just add extra routes.

Don't forget to substitute IP addresses, port numbers, and interface names as
appropriate. I have udev rules to rename the link to the iPhone based on the
MAC address. You may not and it will likely show up as another eth* device.
Table and mark numbers can be changed, as long as they are consistent like they
are now.

1. Create a routing table *with* a default gateway, for every link.

   ```
   ip route add 172.20.10.0/24 dev iphone0 table 1234
   ip route add default via 172.20.10.1 dev iphone0 table 1234

   ip route add 192.0.2.0/24 dev eth0 table 4321
   ip route add default via 192.0.2.1 dev eth0 table 4321
   ```
2. Since IP routing rules are only *that*, IP-layer, mark traffic intended
   for whichever link, using iptables. Notice how it is *pre-routing*.

   ```
   iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 22 -j MARK --set-mark 1
   iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j MARK --set-mark 2
   ```
3. Create routing rules to deal with having multiple default gateways. These
   must come first, as they force traffic to go back out the same interface
   whence it came, rather than out another if, for example, you changed which
   interface SSH traffic should use.

   ```
   ip rule add from 172.20.10.2 table 1234 priority 1000
   ip rule add from 192.0.2.2 table 4321 priority 1001
   ```
4. (Optional, unless traffic on one subnet isn't routable by the gateway on the
   other subnet — e.g., *maybe* RFC 1918 traffic) Create routing rules to force
   traffic to the subnets to which you are directly connected to go through the
   appropriate interface, regardless of what you specified as the link to be
   used for a particular traffic type.

   ```
   ip rule add to 172.20.10.0/24 table 1234 pref 1002
   ip rule add to 192.0.2.0/24 table 4321 pref 1003
   ```
5. Create routing rules

   ```
   ip rule add fwmark 1 table 1234 pref 1004
   ip rule add fwmark 2 table 4321 pref 1005
   ```
6. Set the default gateway for all other traffic.

   ```
   ip route add default via 192.0.2.1 dev eth0 # implicit "table main" here
   ```

As for changing what connection is used on the fly, there is shouldn't be a
command in the official repositories (if written and published at all). You'd
have to write a script that would just read the existing rule from the RPDB,
calculate the 'opposite' table, delete the old rule, and make a rule for marked
traffic to use the other table. For example:

```
#! /bin/sh

case $1 in
  ssh)  PREF=1004
  http) PREF=1005
  *)    echo "Unknown." 1>&2; exit 1
esac

TABLE=`ip rule list | grep ^$PREF: | awk '{print $NF}' | rev`
ip rule del pref $PREF
ip rule add fwmark 1 table $TABLE pref $PREF
```

Here the choice of table number from above matters because I'm using a cheap
trick to ‘toggle’ the table number.

Not tested as I don't have what I need handy.

The above can be generalized to other situations with two links and different
addressing schemes.

Also, if you are using OpenSSH, it has a flag to specify the address to which to be bound, `-b`. Since the above set up rules to route based on source address, you can just do `ssh -b insert_iphone_address_here user@example.com` or the other address to chose which route to take. I'm not aware of any of the major browsers allowing the user to set the bind address.